# Asserting java.util.Date fields in Test

Tags: java, testing, assertj

I'm writing integration test for my DAO services. I perform that by using dao insert methods and then reading objects from database and asserting all fields with orginal objects.

I want to use assertj-core to make assertions. Especially [isEqualToComparingFieldByField](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#isEqualToComparingFieldByField(A)) .

But there is problem with java.util.Date fields. They return identical getTime() value but aren't equal.

Currently I ignore these fields in isEqualToComparingFieldByField assertion and then comapre with hasSameTimeAs method.

```
assertThat(object).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(other, "time");
assertThat(object.getTime()).hasSameTimeAs(other.getTime());
```

Is any way to provide custom comparator to isEqualToComparingFieldByField method for given type(in this case java.util.Date) or any other solution to assert two objects field by field avoiding this issue?

Comment: Till the java 8 date/time classes, consider `java.util.Date` equality just based on the `getTime()`, and for other purposes (fields) test Calendar. In Date the corresponding "field" constructor is deprecated and advises to use Calendar.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of specifying a custom comparator for a given field type in "field by field" comparison - I'm not sure there is an elegant of introducing that in AssertJ (but I'd love to be proven wrong).

What you can do is to define a comparator for your objects, and use it like this:

```
assertThat(frodo).usingComparator(raceNameComparator).isEqualTo(pippin);
```

See [assertj-examples](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/BasicAssertionsExamples.java#L122) project for a full working example.

I know it requires work to write the Comparator, it's the price to pay to have full control over the comparison strategy used.

Comment: So, if AssertJ doesn't support this kind of problems, could you recommend me another testing/asserting library where I can compare two objects field by field (includning mentioned date issue)?

Comment: You can give a try to unitils (http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-reflectionassert.html) also I don't know if it has the feature you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you take your objects from sql, you are mixing Timestamps and Date.

```
Date date = theTwoTowers.getReleaseDate();
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());

// timestamp is a Date, it can be compared to date 
assertThat(date.equals(timestamp)).isTrue();

// as date is not a Timestamp, it can't be equal to timestamp  
assertThat(timestamp.equals(date)).isFalse();
```

This link can help you : https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/273

Comment: I have seen this converstion but it doesn't say how can I resolve my problem. Is any option to assert Date field by isEqualToComparingFieldByField method with e.g. hasSameTimeAs? I want to avoid writing separate assertions only for java.util.Date fields.

Comment: I don't think this issue has been written in assertJ issues. 
isEqualToComparingFieldByField could be overrode : if the element of the object is a Date, you do something different for equality but it's very dangerous for future evolutions/changes of AssertJ.

Another way to do what you want is to create an ObjectA so you have  YourActualObject = ObjectA + Date.You can then use  isEqualToComparingFieldByField for your object B and check your Date separately.

Comment: I attach similar solution in my question : assertThat(object).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(other, "time");
assertThat(object.getTime()).hasSameTimeAs(other.getTime()); So there is no other "nice" solution?

Comment: Following Deuskull comment, try switching actual and expected values, it might solve your problem as you will end performing date.equals(timestamp) instead of timestamp.equals(date) .

having said that, it's more a hack than a clean solution.